# Retain radio button state that affects other elements

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I have a form with lots of inputs. I am using jQuery so if a person selects the answer "Yes" a text box appears if they click "no" nothing appears. My problem is when a person submits the page and the page runs through the PHP validation if it throws the page (incurs reload) back with an error while I can get the Radio button to remember the value chosen (using PHP) it will not re-show the textbox if the user clicked yes.

Basically:
User Picks Yes, text box shows. User submits page, page thrown back due to validation error. Radio button remembers state "Yes" but text box is not shown unless re clicking yes.

Any idea how I can get the textbox to show up?

jQuery

```
$("input[name='radioButton']").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "Yes")
    {
        $("#txt1").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#txt1").hide(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Set the CSS display property of the textbox with PHP to show/hide the element based on the same condition you're using to set the radio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look to the checked radio button on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("input[name='radioButton'][value='Yes']").is(':checked'))
        $("#txt1").show();
    else
        $("#txt1").hide(); 
});
```

EDIT: Changed to use ".is(':checked')"

Comment: RE: your edit: I considered that option as well (the value=) and it should work and is pretty descriptive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ryan Henderson, it worked fine once I changed the .load to .ready

Comment: @MarkH Wow, I have no idea why I typed "load" there. Of course it should be "ready"! Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: This is the correct way to do it. From Ryan Henderson's answer:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("input[name='radioButton'][value='Yes']").is(':checked'))
        $("#txt1").show();
    else
        $("#txt1").hide(); 
});
```

It's not supposed to replace your current change event handler. It basically checks the value of the radio button when the page is loaded.

Comment: You need to add ":checked" to the selector. This will always find a radio button that has a value of "Yes", whether it's selected or not.

Comment: @RyanHenderson If you add ":checked", the selector won't return a match if the state of the radio button is unchecked.

Comment: Exactly. According to the OP, the "#txt1" element should only be shown in the "Yes" radio button is selected.

Comment: A named radio button `.val()` should return the currently selected button from a group.

Comment: @RyanHenderson I see your point, but if the selector returns an empty set of matched elements because the radio button is unchecked, wouldn't trying to get its .val() cause a null exception?

Comment: @Uqi No, it would be empty as none are selected - thus I believe your code should be fine.

Comment: Do you have a reference link for the ".val()" technique? I tried searching, but can't find any documentation.

Comment: @Uqi In fact, here is a Fiddle where this is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/bWbZ3/

Comment: I admit error on my part after testing, you need the `:checked` or similar i.e. `$("input[name='radioButton']:checked").val()`

Comment: @RyanHenderson You're absolutely right. I was thinking of it as a checkbox that is either checked or not rather than a set of radio buttons.

Comment: @Uqi Since the OP selected your answer, please update so that it actually works. I wouldn't want anyone else trying to do it and getting confused.

Comment: @MarkH My method is actually wrong. Ryan Henderson's answer is what you're looking for.